# NUnit Test Adapter is showing duplicate failed tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nunit, nunittestadapter

I am using NUnit Framework 2.6.4 and NUnit Test Adapter 2.0.0 (which seems to support up to 2.6.4). I am running Visual Studio 2015.

I have noticed in the Test Explorer Window that when tests fail, they show up as duplicates 3-4 times in a row the failed section. Has anyone else seen this? Is this a setting (is the test being run more than once?) or could this potentially be a bug?

I have not noticed any of my passing tests being duplicated.

My end goal is to clean it up. I only want to see the failed test once.

Comment: You have to report to the developer at GitHub. I personally experience multiple issues and switch to other frameworks. Note that 2.x is no more updated. You have to upgrade to 3.x and try again.

Comment: Actually, that's correct but misleading. NUnit 2.x is no longer updated, but his problem is related to the adapter, not to NUnit itself. The NUnit VS Adapter continues to be updated because each new release of VS causes new bugs! BTW, the NUnit 3 VS Adapter also exists as a completely separate package on NuGet and in the VS Gallery.

Answer (score 3):

Check to see if you have installed both the nuget package and the vsix extension. With VS2015, if you have both installed, both are used. Prior to 2015, the extension was used in preference, which caused different kinds of problems. :-)